# How to calculate distance by importing coordinates from a text file using python function

Tags: python

Save the following data in a file named coordinates.txt.

```
A,0,0;B,3,4
C,4,7;D,2,9
E,8,2;F,0,6
```

Each line of the file contains the Name of a Point and its X-Y coordinates, a semicolon, then the Name of a second Point and its X-Y coordinates in the form:
`<Name1>:X1,Y1;<Name2>:X2,Y2`;

Write a Script to calculate the Distance and City Block Distance using the formulae given below:

```
distance = math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2) 
City Block Distance = |(X1-X2)|+|(Y1-Y2)|
```

So, the Output of the Script becomes:

- From A (0, 0) to B (3, 4): actual distance 5.000; city block distance 7
- From C (4, 7) to D (2, 9): actual distance 2.828; city block distance 4
- From E (8, 2) to F (0, 6): actual distance 8.944; city block distance 12.

I have tried importing data from excel but I am new so don't have much idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `coordinates.txt` in the same directory as the Python script:

```
with open("coordinates.txt", 'r') as coordinates_file:
    for line in coordinates_file:
        # delete trailing new-line character
        line = line.rstrip()
        # unpack points (e.g. "A,0,0")
        point_1, point_2 = line.split(";")
        # name_* is for example "A"; loc*_tmp is a string representation of coords
        name_1, *loc1_tmp = point_1.split(",")
        # change coords to int
        loc1 = [int(loc) for loc in loc1_tmp]
        name_2, *loc2_tmp = point_2.split(",")
        loc2 = [int(loc) for loc in loc2_tmp]
        euclidian_distance = math.sqrt((loc1[0] - loc2[0])**2 + (loc1[1] - loc2[1])**2)
        block_distance = abs(loc1[0] - loc2[0]) + abs(loc1[1] - loc2[1])
        print("The distances between {} and {}:".format(name_1, name_2))
        print("Euclidian distance {}".format(euclidian_distance))
        print("Block distance {}".format(block_distance))
```